# How to make mysql join include null values?

Tags: mysql

This query works just fine

```
   SELECT `category`
          , `product`
          , `(SUM(CASE WHEN stock.is_out = false and stocktrxn.is_defective = false
                       THEN qty 
                       ELSE 0 END) 
            - SUM(CASE WHEN stock.is_out = true 
                       THEN qty 
                       ELSE 0 END))` AS `qty_available`
          , `(SUM(CASE WHEN stock.is_out = false a`nd stocktrxn.is_defective = true THEN qty ELSE 0 END))` AS `qty_defective`
          , `(SUM(CASE WHEN stock.is_out = false THEN qty ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN stock.is_out = true THEN qty ELSE 0 END))` AS `qty_sum` 
     FROM `product` 
LEFT JOIN `stocktrxn` 
       ON `product`.`id` = `stocktrxn`.`product_no`
LEFT JOIN `stock` 
       ON `stock`.`tra_no` = `stocktrxn`.`tra_no `
    GROUP BY `stock`.`warehouse_id`, `product` 
    ORDER BY `category`, `product_name`, `product_type`, `dqty1`, `dqty2`
```

but once I add `stock`.`warehouse_id` = `:warehouse_id` I end up with a result with products without transactions omitted.

What's the right approach to adding the where?

Comment: You want to add `stock.warehouse_id = :warehouse_id` as a where clause?  The problem will be that defeats the purpose of having a left outer join with stock.  The result can only include results that have a stock row in order for stock.warehouse_id = :warehouse_id to be true.

You can do `where stock.warehouse_id = :warehouse_id or stock.warehouse_id  is null` to include rows that are either in the warehouse or have no stock.

Comment: @SteveBauer hmmm...greate idea, let me try

Comment: @SteveBauer it works thanks!

Comment: That is a bit of an odd mix, you are getting product in a particular warehouse or in no warehouse.  I would think you would normally want to include product in other warehouses but show they had no quantity in this warehouse, moving the `stock.warehouse_id = :warehouse_id` to the join condition for stock should do this.  ` ON `stock`.`tra_no` = `stocktrxn`.`tra_no ` and stock.warehouse_id = :warehouse_id`